# Running a Snow Leopard 10.6.7 Image on an AMD: The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system

Tags: cpu, vmware

I am quite frustrated so I have turned to this medium in hoping to get an answer. After reading thousands of forums and trying out various methods (I have lost track what I have tried already) I still haven't solved my problem.

That is, I am trying to run a Mac OS X Snow Leopard VMware image 10.6.7 on my AMD quad core computer with VMware Workstation 9.0.

My latest attempt involves opening the specific configuration .vmx file (which is linked to a VMware image .vmdk) and hence booting it with help of a kernel (darwin.iso). A description of these steps undertaken can be found here: http://anonymous00.hubpages.com/hub/Installing-Mac-OSX-On-Windows

I have tried different VMware images and different kernels, but I keep getting the error: "The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system (...)". So I am guessing that something went wrong when unlocking the Mac OS X (I don't know how to check this however, since the Mac OS X Guest Host seems to be installed and unlocked correctly, that is it appears in the list of available guest hosts).

So community, what do you think I should try?

A couple of things I have tried already:

- Applying a mask (adding the line cpuid.1.eax = "0000:0000:0000:0001:0000:0110:1010:0101" in the .vmx file)
- Trying to install the operating system instead of running (hence booting from a .iso file): this didn't work as well: my computer didn't recognize the operating system.
- Different versions of kernels and different VMware images (including images that are meant only for AMD processors)

Please help! P.s.: yes, I have enabled Virtualization in my BIOS.

---

**My computer specifications:**

AMD A6-3410MX APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 1.60GHz;
Memory (RAM): 6.00GB;
System type: 64-bit;
Model: HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC

Comment: Mac OS X in VMware is only supported in Apple hosts already running OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but with an AMD 8-core CPU, and I found the cause: it is in the structure of your APU. Mac OS X only supports only Sandy Bridge-type CPUs with GPU. For now this has no solution.